# more handwriting help

Tags: handwriting

[image: phrase between Hausvater and Hausmutter]

On the left I can see the "Hausvater" is Johan Michael Manner citizen of W_____
born ?
Ob________ date 10 May 1806.    Is the "Ob" word a city or town do you think?

On the right is the "Hausmutter" but it is too damaged to make out more than Joha...1810.

Can you help with the phrase in the middle ending with the date 7 July(?) 1836 ?
Below this info (but not pictured) are the fathers' names of the "Hausvater" and "Hausmutter".

Also, what does this figure indicate?[image]

Thank you so much for any help you can give me.

Comment: The figure at the bottom of your post might be the sign for the currency Gulden or parts of the Gulden, i.e. the Kreuzer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left side:

**Hausvater**

> Johann Michael Mauer
>
> Bürger(?) u. Weingärtner
>
> geboren in
>
> Oberriexingen, den 10. Mai 1806

Basically name and profession. The "Bürger" part I'm unsure, but the second ("Weingärtner") word is "wine grower" - Then "born in"

Middle

> Kopuliert in Enzweihingen,

That's "married in Enzweihingen" - today "kopulieren" is only used to describe sexual intercourse, but it used to be used  for "to marry".

Right

> **Hausmutter**
> ...(that's all too hard to read for me, I could only guess)

Oberriexingen and Enzweihingen are two small villages near *Vaihingen/Enz*, a small city in the south of Germany near Stuttgart.

Comment: It seems to say Johanna Frederike under Hausmutter, and the surname of the Hausvater is not Manner but Mauer

Comment: On second thought, you are right regarding the surname - The first name of the wife, well that *could* be, but could be anything else...

Comment: Well, anything that starts with "Johan"